# Django tests errors after changing from MemcachedCache to PyMemcacheCache

Tags: django, pymemcached

I'm in the process of upgrading my project to Django 4.1.13 from 4.0. MemcachedCache has been removed from Django 4.1 so I've switched to PyMemcacheCache. I can `python manage.py runserver` my local server with no problems. However, when I run the tests (with `--settings=test`) I get errors

pymemcache.exceptions.MemcacheError: All servers seem to be down right now

in settings/test.py i have `CACHE_BACKEND = 'locmem:///'`

Test were running fine on Django 4.0